# Lambda fetching multiple records with contains query returns empty

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, list, lambda

I have this code:

```
public JsonResult EkranBilgiListele(List<int> ids)
{
    dbReklam db = new dbReklam();
    //int[] ids = { 14, 16 }; ids comes like this
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var secilenEkranlar = db.tbl_Ekranlar.Where(ekranlar => ids.Contains(ekranlar.sektorID));
    return Json(secilenEkranlar);
}
```

And an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("EkranBilgiListele")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { ids: arraySecilenEkranlarID },

    success: function (data) {
        console.log('---->' + data.ekranAd);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true
});
```

However, using breakpoints and results view always returns `'empty'` and the console returns `'undefined'`

Answer (score 2):

Really sorry I  wrote wrong query!

Writing right one.

```
public JsonResult EkranBilgiListele(List<int> ids)
    {
        //int[] ids = { 14, 16 }; ids comes like this
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var secilenEkranlar = db.tbl_Ekranlar.Where(ekranlar => ids.Contains(ekranlar.ekranID));
        return Json(secilenEkranlar);
    }
```

ajax code, changed a little bit:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EkranBilgiListele")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { ids: arraySecilenEkranlarID },
            success: function (secilenEkranlar) {
                $.each(secilenEkranlar, function (i, ekranlar) {
                    console.log(ekranlar.ekranAd);
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('İlçeler Çekilemedi.' + ex);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If this is the answer that solves your problem you should accept it by clicking the green tick. If it does not, you should edit the details into your question.